# Page Swipe Gesture jQuery HTML

Tags: jquery, iphone, user-interface, interface, gesture-recognition

I have been looking for a page swipe script (Like how the home screen pages on the iPhone change.) I have not been able to find one. The closest one I can find is [this demo](http://nooshu.com/explore/jquery-iphone-animation/) but it does not support iPhone gestures.

It does not need to be jQuery but it would be preferred.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an HTML5 framework called jQTouch that is compatible with jQuery and has support for the swipe event. 
https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/callbackevents

Comment: But do you know of any examples of it?

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe